# Direct Product of Cyclic Groups and Quotient Groups

Tags: group-theory

Let G = $Z_4$ x $Z_6$ be the direct product of cyclic groups $Z_4$ and $Z_6$. Let N = <(2,3)> be a normal subgroup of G. Show that G/N $\simeq$ $Z_{12}$

What I have so far..

Given that |N| = 2, the order of $|G/N| = |G|/|N| = 24/2 = 12 = 2^{2}$*$3$

The number of abelian groups = $p^{(2)}$$p^{(1)}$ = 2

So the order 12 abelian groups are : $Z_4$ x $Z_3$ and $Z_2$ x $Z_2$ x $Z_3$

From this, I claim G/N $\simeq$ $Z_{12}$

How would I prove this from what I have so far? Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, $\mathbb{Z}_{12} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{4} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$. Hence, one strategy would be to demonstrate an element of order $4$ in the quotient group to differentiate it from $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$. Alternatively, you can specify a generator to show that $G/N$ is cyclic.

Comment: Why do you think your group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3$?

Comment: @paw88789: doesn't the element $(1, 3)$ have order $4$ in the quotient group?

Comment: @AWertheim: Good point!  I need to practice my quotient groups.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. Why do I have to demonstrate that there is an element of order 4? What does this signify?

Also, a silly question but why does (1,3) have order 4 and not 2?

Comment: @SquiresMcGee: Because $\mathbb{Z}_{4}\times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$ has an element of order $4$, whereas $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$ doesn't. Hence, if your group has an element of order $4$, it can't be $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$. Also, $(1,3)$ has order $4$ because $(1,3)+(1,3) = (2,0)$, which is NOT in $N$, whereas $(1,3)+(1,3)+(1,3)+(1,3)=(0,0)$, which is in $N$ (recall the order of an element $g$ in a quotient group is the least integer $n$ such $g^{n} \in N$).

Answer (score 4):

A straightforward consequence of Lagrange's Theorem tells us that $|G/N|=12$.

The idea now is to construct a morphism
$$
\varphi\colon G\to\mathbb{Z}_{12}
$$
such that $ker(\varphi)=N$. So by the first isomorphism theorem we deduce the result.

Since $G$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ are $\mathbb{Z}$-module we can extend by linearity the morphism defined by
$$
(1,0)\mapsto 3,\ (0,1)\mapsto 2
$$
It is easy to check that $N=ker(\varphi)$.

Comment: Nice answer, +1 :)

Comment: Yep, very elegant. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Good answer.  @Squires, this is a good approach to any question dealing with an isomorphism like this.  The first isomorphism theory pops up all over the place.  In fact, it's often called the Fundamental Homomorphism Theorem.

Comment: Got it, thanks Jeff. I did go through over that theorem, didn't see it's application here until now.